# Can I have multiple query statements inside an If statement of sql trigger?

Tags: sql, triggers, phpmyadmin, database-trigger

```
DECLARE **cusname** varchar;

IF(New.BecomeVolunteer = 'Yes') 
THEN 
SELECT CusName INTO cusname FROM customer WHERE CusID = NEW.CusID;

INSERT INTO staff (StaffName, StaffTel, StaffDOB, Availability, Duties, [enter image description here][1]StaffType)
VALUES
(**cusname**, '07589634598', '1965-05-13', 'Tue,Wed,SatPM','Collecting Tickets,Ushering Customers to Seats,Looking after the Artists', 'Volunteer');
END IF
```

I have a table staff and I want to get the 'CusName' from 'customer' table and set it to the variable 'cusname'. Then I want to use that variable in my Insert statement as a value for 'StaffName' attribute'

I haven't worked much with triggers yet but I understand the basic syntax to make simple statements work but this one continuously giving an error. I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out what's wrong in here.

```html
IF(New.BecomeVolunteer = 'Yes') 
THEN 
INSERT INTO staff (StaffName, StaffTel, StaffDOB, Availability, Duties, StaffType)
VALUES
('Jaamees', '07589634598', '1965-05-13', 'Tue,Wed,SatPM','Collecting Tickets,Ushering Customers to Seats,Looking after the Artists', 'Volunteer');
END IF
```

The following statement works perfectly fine but not the above one (when I want to add a variable).

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

`IF` by default works with a single statement.  If you want to execute more than one statement inside an `IF`, then use `BEGIN...END`:

```
IF (New.BecomeVolunteer = 'Yes') 
BEGIN
    SELECT CusName INTO cusname FROM customer WHERE CusID = NEW.CusID;
    INSERT INTO staff (StaffName, StaffTel, StaffDOB, Availability, Duties, StaffType)
    VALUES
        (cusname, '07589634598', '1965-05-13', 'Tue,Wed,SatPM',
        'Collecting Tickets,Ushering Customers to Seats,Looking after the Artists',
        'Volunteer');
END;
```

Comment: thx Tim. Its the variable declaration that seems to cause a problem I think so it still doesn't run even if I replace IF with BEGIN. Am I declaring and setting the variable the right way?

Comment: Try `DECLARE cusname varchar(100)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in one statement:

```
IF (New.BecomeVolunteer = 'Yes') THEN 
    INSERT INTO staff (StaffName, StaffTel, StaffDOB, Availability, Duties, StaffType)
        SELECT c.cusname, '07589634598', '1965-05-13', 'Tue,Wed,SatPM', 'Collecting Tickets,Ushering Customers to Seats,Looking after the Artists', 'Volunteer')
        FROM customer c
        WHERE c.CustId = NEW.CusID
```

And, you can even remove the `IF`:

```
    INSERT INTO staff (StaffName, StaffTel, StaffDOB, Availability, Duties, StaffType)
        SELECT c.cusname, '07589634598', '1965-05-13', 'Tue,Wed,SatPM', 'Collecting Tickets,Ushering Customers to Seats,Looking after the Artists', 'Volunteer')
        FROM customer c
        WHERE c.CustId = NEW.CusID AND
              New.BecomeVolunteer = 'Yes';
```